# SPARQL Dividing two values from two queries

Tags: sparql

I have two SPARQL queries ,one fetching the total no of defects,and second fetching the total no. of test cases .I want to divide one count result to another count i.e (total no. of defects/total no. of test cases).
How can I divide two queries result using divide operator.

Anyone can suggest me on same?

```
    PREFIX process: <http://jazz.net/ns/process#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX merge: <http://jazz.net/ns/lqe/merge/>
    PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX oslc: <http://open-services.net/ns/core#>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
    PREFIX rtc_merged: <http://jazz.net/ns/lqe/merge/gensym/cm/>
    PREFIX oslc_config: <http://open-services.net/ns/config#>
    PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>


    SELECT DISTINCT
      ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea
      ?rtc_merged_Defect1_shortId_COUNT
    WHERE{
      {
        SELECT DISTINCT
          ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea
          (COUNT(DISTINCT ?rtc_merged_Defect1_shortId) AS ?rtc_merged_Defect1_shortId_COUNT)
        WHERE{
          VALUES( ?rtc_merged_Defect1_paUri )
          {
            ( <https://localhost:9443/ccm/process/project-areas/__ANzQBasEeegkPxZTDywOA> )
          }
          ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri process:projectArea ?rtc_merged_Defect1_paUri.
          ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri oslc:instanceShape ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri_instanceShape.
          ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri_instanceShape merge:mergeShape rtc_merged:Defect.
          OPTIONAL {
            ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri process:projectArea ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumValue.
            OPTIONAL {?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumValue rdfs:label|dcterms:title ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumName.}
          }
          OPTIONAL {?rtc_merged_Defect1_ver dcterms:isVersionOf ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri; rdf:type oslc_config:VersionResource.}
          ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri oslc:shortId ?rtc_merged_Defect1_shortId.
          BIND( IF (bound(?rtc_merged_Defect1_ver), concat(str(?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri), "?oslc_config.context="), ?rtc_merged_Defect1_uri) as ?rtc_merged_Defect1)
          BIND( IF(bound(?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumName), ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumName, IF(bound(?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumValue), ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea_enumValue, "")) as ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea)
        }
        GROUP BY ?rtc_merged_Defect1_projectArea
      }
    }  //This is my first query.
===============================================================


   PREFIX process: <http://jazz.net/ns/process#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX merge: <http://jazz.net/ns/lqe/merge/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX oslc: <http://open-services.net/ns/core#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rqm_merged: <http://jazz.net/ns/lqe/merge/gensym/qm/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX oslc_config: <http://open-services.net/ns/config#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>


SELECT DISTINCT
  ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea
  ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_shortId_COUNT
WHERE{
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT
      ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea
      (COUNT(DISTINCT ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_shortId) AS ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_shortId_COUNT)
    WHERE{
      VALUES( ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_paUri )
      {
        ( <https://localhost:9443/qm/process/project-areas/_EazMoBatEeeR-7d5-ZtSzw> )
      }
      ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri process:projectArea ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_paUri.
      ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri oslc:instanceShape ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri_instanceShape.
      ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri_instanceShape merge:mergeShape rqm_merged:QM%20Test%20Case.
      OPTIONAL {
        ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri process:projectArea ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumValue.
        OPTIONAL {?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumValue rdfs:label|dcterms:title ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumName.}
      }
      OPTIONAL {?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_ver dcterms:isVersionOf ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri; rdf:type oslc_config:VersionResource.}
      ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri oslc:shortId ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_shortId.
      BIND( IF (bound(?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_ver), concat(str(?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri), "?oslc_config.context="), ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_uri) as ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1)
      BIND( IF(bound(?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumName), ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumName, IF(bound(?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumValue), ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea_enumValue, "")) as ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea)
    }
    GROUP BY ?rqm_merged_QMTestCase1_projectArea
  }
}
```

Comment: You first and second query are exactly the same.

Comment: And I don't understand why you have a single sub-SELECT in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use use two sub-SELECT queries (I'm using stubs here since your current SPARQL queries are confusing (duplicates and using an unnecessary sub-SELECT)):

```
SELECT (?cnt1/?cnt2 AS ?result) WHERE {

// first query
{
  SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?cnt1) WHERE {
     ...
  }
}

// second query
{
  SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?cnt2) WHERE {
     ...
  }
}

}
```

Comment: yeah,Sorry its my mistake.now just edited my second query.First find the total no. of defects and second query find total no. of test cases.I want to Defect Density= total Defects/Total test cases

Comment: Ok, but why do you have a nested SELECT? I don't see why this is necessary

Comment: thank u for quick response ,i used your given approach bt i got error on line no.1( CRRGW5605E An com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException error occurred when validating the input SPARQL string, caused by Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 20. Was expecting one of: "not" ... "as" ... "in" ... ... ... ... ... ... ... "=" ... "!=" ... ">" ... "<" ... "<=" ... ">=" ... "||" ... "&&" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... .)

Comment: Your are using an old version of Jena. I don't know if this supports SPARQL 1.1. Latest version of Jena is `3.2.0`, yours is more than 2 years old ...

Comment: @AKSW the error might be a result of the missing own parenthesis in `SELECT (?cnt1/?cnt2) AS ?result) where`.

Comment: @AmrutaRaut: I had an error in the part of the projection variables (Joshua Taylor found it), see the updated query.